# Exception using ProgressDialog in BroadcastReceiver - token null is not for an application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

**UserStream.java -**

```
public class UserStream extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
         if(action.equals("com.aser.main.ReceiverConnection")){
            Log.i(TAG, "Received intent from UserInteraction service");

            if(intent.getExtras().get("key").equals("startDialog"))
            {
                System.out.println("the wokring HUD started...");
                connectionDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                connectionDialog.setMessage("Working ...");
                connectionDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                connectionDialog.setCancelable(false);
                connectionDialog.show();  //exception here
            }
    }
```

**NOTE:**

My calling class is a IntentService class with the following code -

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.aser.main.ReceiverConnection");
intent.putExtra("key","startDialog");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**Error Log:**

```
12-15 20:48:17.179: E/ACRA(5237): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
12-15 20:48:17.179: E/ACRA(5237):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:588)
12-15 20:48:17.179: E/ACRA(5237):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
12-15 20:48:17.179: E/ACRA(5237):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
12-15 20:48:17.179: E/ACRA(5237):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
12-15 20:48:17.179: E/ACRA(5237):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
12-15 20:48:17.179: E/ACRA(5237):   at com.aser.main.UserStream.onReceive(UserStream.java:73)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not show a view components in the broadcast receiver. To show the progress dialog start the activity and show there.